# python vector apply mean across axis in chunks of size 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a long vector (50,000 datapoints)
and I want to reduce it by applying mean in chunks of 5. (So I will get vector at the size of 10,000).
For example, 
if the vector is

```
[1,8,-1,0,2 , 6,8,11,4,6]
```

the output will be

```
[2,7]
```

What is the most efficient way to do so?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't be the average of the chunks be 2 and 7?

Answer (score 1):

When you know that the vector is always divisible by 5:

```
import numpy as np

vec = np.array([1,8,-1,0,2 , 6,8,11,4,6])
averaged = vec.reshape(-1, 5).mean(axis=1).flatten()
print(averaged)
```

Output

```
array([2., 7.])
```